# Merge two dataframes with different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with different sizes and I want to merge them.

It's like an "update" to a dataframe column based on another dataframe with different size.

**This is an example input:**

**dataframe 1**

```
  CODUSU Situação TIPO1
0    1AB        P    A0
1    2C3        C    B1
2    3AB        P    C1
```

**dataframe 2**

```
  CODUSU Situação  ABC
0    1AB        A    3
1    3AB        A    4
```

**My output should be like this:**

**dataframe 3**

```
  CODUSU Situação TIPO1
0    1AB        A    A0
1    2C3        C    B1
2    3AB        A    C1
```

PS: I did it through loop but I think there should better and easier way to make it!

I read this content: [pandas merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) and wrote this code:

```
df3=df1.merge(df2, on=['CODUSU'], how='left', indicator=False)
df3['Situação'] = np.where((df3['Situação_x'] == 'P') & (df3['Situação_y'] == 'A') , df3['Situação_y'] , df3['Situação_x'])
df3=df3.drop(columns=['Situação_x', 'Situação_y','ABC'])
df3 = df3[['CODUSU','Situação','TIPO1']]
```

And Voilà, **df3** is exactly what I needed!
Thanks for everyone!

PS: I already found my answer, is there a better place to answer my own question?

Answer (score 2):

```
df1.merge(df2,how='left', left_on='CODUSU', right_on='CODUSU')
```

This should do the trick.

Also, worth noting that if you want your resultant data frame to not contain the column ABC, you'd use df2.drop("ABC") instead of just df2.

Comment: That command returns this:                                                                                                >CODUSU Situação_x TIPO1 Situação_y  ABC
>0    1AB          P    A0          A  3.0
>1    2C3          C    B1        NaN  NaN
>2    3AB          P    C1          A  4.0`